# Drupal 7 - Functionality for multi-select of nodes and then action to send email to a manually entered email address

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform, drupal-rules

I have a webform setup along with a rule that creates a new content type called 'Idea' with most of the submitted data (so that comments can be made on node of type 'Idea')

The webform is for new ideas for the business and depending on the idea it then needs emailed to the correct person in the business so they can respond.

I know a way of doing this would be to create a drop-down list in the webform and assign an email address to that record (eg. IT > (email would go to > it.dave@company.com) but they don't want it to be in the control of the user in case they select the wrong person for the webform submission to go to, they want to be able to manage this themselves manually.

What is the best way to approach this?

I was thinking, is there some sort of multi-select option where you could select one or multiple nodes from the content page and then manually enter an email address, hit a submit button, which emails them.

They want to be able to enter the email part manually and not choose from a list as it may end up going to a large range of different people, not one of a pre-determined list.

I was possibly thinking if rules or workflow or workbench might help but never used the last 2 before, but if someone knows of a way that might be best to approach this it would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to find a common point between nodes , so you can create a taxonomy vocabulary and associate a tag on each node corresponding and automatically associate tag to list of emails

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1

Use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to create a Rules Component, which includes whatever Rules Conditions you might need (if any), and with a Rules Action to **Send an eMail**, for each of those fields you want to be updated.

#### Step 2

Create a view of the group of nodes for which those eMails should be generated. Then transform that view into a view that uses [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), and use the technique documented in "[How to use Rules to create a custom bulk operation for a VBO view?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/88)". In doing so, you'll then be able to use the Rules Component from Step 1.

#### Tutorial

To get the idea, have a look at the video about [Using Rules components with VBO](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-components-with-vbo)" which uses a Rules Component with (only) 1 parameter. If you want even more, then also watch the subsequent "[Using Rules components with more than one parameter](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-componens-with-more-than-one-parameter)" video.

Attention: to process like 100.000 entities at once is quite a challenge (memory requirements, etc). Therefor you might want to also watch the video about "[More details about VBO settings](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/more-details-about-vbo-settings)" ... Before you are tempted to use VBO for processing them all at once ...